# Android Studio: "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1" and SDK Manager folder is...missing?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, exception

So while installing flutter and Android Studio. I did encounter several problems. First is the "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1" when i run the program. this thing always appears in my runs no matter which folder/emulator I do. So I tried to go and check several videos. including uploaded by BD Technic(youtube) how to fix this kinds of problem. I also went to SDK Manager and check if the SDK Command-line tools are check. I check and the problem is still there. i tried to recheck and the problem is still there. Then I uncheck the Hide Obselete Package and see if the Android SDK tools(obselete) was check(according to BD Technic) and the problem IS still there.

So I decided to go use the Flutter Doctor --android-licenses and shows that the problem(screenshot) is this.
[image]

I went to the folder and see if maybe it was bugged/corrupted then I realized...I don't have the SDKmanager folder...
normally when you run this android-license it should run differently and show "Accept [y/n]" base on youtube videos I watched.

So my question is 2: How to fix "Exception:Gradle Task..."?knowing my license isn't working. I tried several guide and it has a similar problem. I'm not sure if having missing SDK Manager is the solution or maybe after you install the license it should be created instead. I have literally different problem compare to other people posting AndroidStudio errors when it comes to exception:gradle task

do I just need to reinstall the entire android studio? as well as the flutter.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the following things:

- Java JDK setup and add it (JAVA_HOME) to environment variables ( Windows operating system).
- Install a Gradle and add it to the environment variables (GRADLE_HOME).
- Install the SDK Android and to add it to the environment variables (ANDROID_HOME).

Then The command is executed in Flutter cmd

```
    flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

I hope I helped you

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290603/android-license-status-unknown-while-running-flutter-doctor) !

Comment: Sorry im little confused. how to add ANDROID_HOME exactly?
as for Gradle, i believe i have gradle(or do i have to install a newer) installed via SDKManager inside the Android Studio > Plugin>Gradle

this is my first time using Android Studio. I apologize for my flaws
i also noticed that i dont have Folder of SDK Manager..?
Basically i check C:\user\acerpc\appdata\local\android\sdk\tools\bin then i dont have SDK manager
you know the one when you run --android-licenses it should say i havent accepted my license but instead it say that sdkfolder not found. reinstall or update your sdk mngr

Comment: Yet i believe i have latest sdk manager(or if you think ididn't, how?) so its little weird at my situation..

Comment: EDIT: after i ask my friend, he said that  C:\user\acerpc\appdata\local\android\sdk\tools\bin 
he has SDKManager config or dll but i dont have, how to have this?